# Flutter Firestore update Map item

Tags: firebase, dictionary, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update an entry in a map in my Firestore collection, but when I use the update method on the document, it updates it, instead of adding new data, I know that when adding an item to an array it goes as follows:

```
'list': FieldValue.arrayUnion([item])
```

but how can a key/value pair be added to a map?

Comment: Please edit the question to be clear about that document data you're working with, and what you would like the document to look like after the update is complete.  Also incude the code you've tried that doesn't work the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are using `set` instead of `update`, although it is hard to tell from your question.